# Unable to call class methods inside its constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm struggling with the implementation of my express router (actually this is a "subrouter" of my main router, that's why I have to extends express.Router)

I have the following code (as an example I simplified it to have only one method) :

```js
import express from "express";

export default class MandatoryFieldsSettingsRouter extends express.Router {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.get('/', this.retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings);
    }

    async retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings(req, res) {
        //some treatment here
    }
}
```

So in the file creating the main router of the application I can defined my subpath like so :

```js
router.use('/mandatory-fields-settings', new MandatoryFieldsSettingsRouter());
```

I have the following error `Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]` at application startup because `this.retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings` is undefined inside the constructor.

I fixed it using this different method declaration :

```js
    // 1st impl : this one is the "wrong" one causing my error
    async retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings(req, res) {
        //some treatment here
    }

    // 2nd impl : this one is the "good" one making my application working
    retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings = async function (req, res) {
        //some treatment here
    }
```

For some reason my company wants me to use the first implementation. Is there any way to use it and keep the way I declare my path inside my constructor ? (I think it's more readable to see every paths declared in the current class just by looking at its constructor).

My company isn't closeminded, if there is absolutely no reason to "ban" the second implementation just let me know and please explain what's the difference between the two if you know it (-> why the first got undefined and the second not ?)

Thanks !

Comment: Note that in both cases, `this` may not mean what you think it means inside `retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings`. Use either `this.retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings.bind(this)` or `(req, res) => this.retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings(req, res)` to have `this` refer to the `MandatoryFieldsSettingsRouter` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first approach if you use the ES2020 syntax for private members (#):

```
async #retrieveMandatoryFieldsSettings(req, res) {
    //some treatment here
}
```

Regards,
Craig